# Scaling and dragging vector graphics in Android

Tags: android, vector, android-canvas, gesture

I would like to be able to incorporate hand gestures to several hundred to thousand dynamically generated polygons so that I can pinch to zoom and drag all of them (not individually) simultaneously in Android. What is the best way to achieve that? Obviously, if there is a library that would be great, but if not could/should I scale/drag the canvas or the view object? An alternative is to convert the vector to a bitmap image, but I think for my purposes it would be very computationally intensive to do all that processing.